# How to hide static files while serving in go?

Tags: go

I'm working on a web app and came to the point where I serve the static css and JS files. In these files I refer like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/tmpfiles/js/app2.js"></script>
```

On the server side I have something like this:

```
router.PathPrefix("/tmpfiles/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/tmpfiles/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("."))))
```

Anybody who has basic knowledge of navigating through directories can see the source code. How do I hide these files and make my application secure?

Comment: Don't serve your assets from your source directory?

Comment: @JimB How should I serve them?

Comment: Put them in their own directory that is isolated from your source.

Comment: You're serving the file from `"."`. When you deploy your code, `"."` usually won't be in the program source, if the program source even exists there. Make the asset location configurable, or at least discoverable.

Comment: @squiguy You mean this way`router.PathPrefix("/tmpfiles/js").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/tmpfiles/js", http.FileServer(http.Dir("js/"))))`

Comment: @JimB That was way over my head. I'm new to backend and I honestly did not understand what you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
 http.FileServer(http.Dir("."))
```

You are telling it to serve files from the current directory (where all your source code lives).

What I typically do is have a folder `/public`, where any static, web accessible files will live.  Then you can do:

```
router.PathPrefix("/tmpfiles/").Handler(
    http.StripPrefix("/tmpfiles/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./public"))))
```

Which will remove the `/tmpfiles/` from the url, and then serve that file from the `public` directory.

Comment: But we still refer it in the html right, like this `<script type="text/javascript" src="/tmpfiles/js/app2.js"></script>`

Comment: correct - the html stays the same.  So it matches any url which starts with "/tmpfiles/", then, in Go, it will take the path "/tmpfiles/js/app2.js", remove the "/tmpfiles", and then see if whatever is left (js/app2.js) exists in ./public